# I am trying to get user country of location from geoplugin.net but i am getting an error

Tags: php

The Error I get is:

> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=&sensor=false)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\SwaziTour\index.php on line 57

my code is as below:

```
echo var_export( unserialize( file_get_contents( 'http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) ) );
```

Comment: `my code is as below;` where ?

Comment: echo var_export(unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))

Answer (score 0):

Don't use geoplugin.net. Try this:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));
print_r($details);
```

Comment: I am getting this error in your code: stdClass Object ( [ip] => ::1 [bogon] => 1 ) 
Warning: file_get_contents(http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=&sensor=false) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in D:\xampp\htdocs\SwaziTour\index.php on line 59

Comment: the code is not able to obtain the IP address, that's where the problem is

Comment: are you trying in local ?

Comment: ahh that's the reason, in localhost visitor's ip address something like this  ::1

Comment: its returning that one

Answer (score -2):

Did you even try to open your link in browser? If you open your url you'll see that you get an error because you don't have an address.

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: read my code carefully, url is there; 'http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']